# How to center this container for IE and other browsers?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, containers

Right now this particular container looks the same on all browsers except IE on a windows.

What do i have to do to fix it?

```
.container {

background-color: #FFFFFF;
margin:0 auto; 
min-height: 170px;
width: 770px;
border:3px solid #000000;
margin-top:30px;
margin-bottom:60px;
}
```

Comment: What's the parent element of this .container? It may be useful to see a link (working example).

Comment: Make sure you have an appropriate DOCTYPE: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/

Answer (score 1):

In your head, paste this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

IE likes to be special.

Comment: I laughed and cried at the same time when I found this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider not supporting sad old browsers. Until then, try the old text-center hack:

```
body { text-align:center; }
.container { text-align: left; width: 770px; margin: 30px auto 60px auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
body{ padding: 0; margin:0; }
#wrapper { position: relative; padding: 0px; width: auto;} 
    .container { width: 770px; min-height: 170px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top:30px; margin-bottom:60px; border:3px solid #000000;}
```

with structure like this:

```
<body>
<div id="wraper">
<div class="container">
your content here
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

i hope it can usefull.. :)